# SSIS - Write new Excel Tab

Tags: sql, excel, ssis

I'm new to SSIS, so forgive me if this has been answered already or is trivial.

I'd like to write some info from a basic SQL Query to a new Excel tab in a file that already exists. What would the steps be for this?

I understand creating a new file or writing to a file in general, I've just not created a new tab/sheet before and am wondering how this could be done.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example for creating a new sheet: http://dwhanalytics.wordpress.com/2011/04/07/ssis-dynamically-generate-excel-tablesheet/